# Cannot get Android app to connect to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

So I've tried this 3 times, and have had no luck successfully making an Android application that will communicate with Firebase. As simple as [the tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-quickstart.html) makes it, I can't help but think either I or it (most likely the former) is missing something.

The sample app I'm making simply holds a TextView that should be updated with any changes to my Firebase at https://dummy-firebase.firebaseio.com/ (since I can't make a public Firebase, if you'd like you can paste the URL of your own firebase to test the code). Here's a snapshot of what's on the Firebase:

[image: Firebase snapshot]

Here's the onCreate of my only Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Firebase f = new Firebase("https://dummy-firebase.firebaseio.com");
    f.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot arg0) {
            TextView textViewSample = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampleTextView);
            textViewSample.setText(arg0.getValue(String.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```

And here's the only XML file, activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sampleTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

And here's a picture of the Manifest so you can clearly see the INTERNET permission:

[image]

Now as I change the data on the Firebase from my browser, I believe the data in the TextView should update. This isn't happening, and I have unsuccessfully tried the to put data using EditTexts and Buttons in the previous Firebase Android project attempts.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to look over this. Because of how simple Firebase seems to set up (and was for the Javascript version) I'm truly stumped as to what I'm doing wrong!

Thanks!!

Comment: By the way, I am running this through Eclipse on a physical 2.2 device (not an emulator) and the device internet connectivity is fine. (Tested this on both Wi-Fi and 3G). Thanks

Comment: Could you try one of the sample apps and see if they work on your device?  That would let us know if there's an issue with your project or if it's an issue with the Android SDK (entirely possible, the SDK is new and in beta).  You should be able to directly install   https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat/raw/master/AndroidChat.apk or https://github.com/firebase/AndroidDrawing/blob/master/AndroidDrawing.apk on your device and test them.

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer: I just tried both the AndroidDrawing and the AndroidChat apps from the Firebase repo on a physical 2.3.6 phone (Samsung Galaxy Ace), they do not work. No Force Close but they just don't connect.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Sounds like an issue on our end then.  We'll take a look and get back to you (probably next week).  Feel free to email support@firebase.com for updates.  Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: How about trying to see if f.setValue("test"); works?

Comment: Android 2.2 has some issues w/ ssl and may not work properly. It's an ongoing thing that we're looking into, but it's not 100% supported yet.


Android 2.3 should work though. Can you add the following to your app and then email the log output to support@firebase.com?


    static {
        Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);
    }

Comment: Actually, this looks like an issue with Android 2.3's SSL implementation. We're working on an update to the library that works around it. Can you try running your app on an emulator with a version >= 3.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try with the latest SDK (v1.0.2) and see if it fixes the problem? We just added a workaround for some of Android's SSL limitations.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/downloads.html

Comment: i m using same sdk and jar files with api level 14 and running in emulator but still i m facing same issue whatever is mentioned above my code is not working for even simple lines of code with eclipse can someone pls tell me whats the issue ? @Greg Soltis

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It is using a pojo class.

```
  buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Creating firebase object
            Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);

            //Getting values to store
            String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
            String address = editTextAddress.getText().toString().trim();

            //Creating Person object
            Person person = new Person();

            //Adding values
            person.setName(name);
            person.setAddress(address);

            //Storing values to firebase
            ref.child("Person").setValue(person);


            //Value event listener for realtime data update
            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        //Getting the data from snapshot
                        Person person = postSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);

                        //Adding it to a string
                        String string = "Name: "+person.getName()+"\nAddress: "+person.getAddress()+"\n\n";

                        //Displaying it on textview
                        textViewPersons.setText(string);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Source: [**Firebase Android Tutorial**](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-android-tutorial-writing-firebase-data/)